# PHP variables are shown undefined

Tags: php

```
<?php
class roxy
{

   function sam()
   {
       $name;
       $class;
       $age;
        echo $name;
        echo $class;
        echo $age;
   }

}
$kush= new roxy();
$kush->name="sachin";
$kush->class=12;
$kush->age=21;
$kush->sam();

?>
```

Here variables are declared localy and when value of variables set through object and after that i call the function it shows me undefined in the result screen.

Comment: This is not how oop works

Comment: Please, don't answer such questions. It shows no effort of trying and the OP clearly doesn't understand anything about PHP/programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your function `sam()` is not referring to the variables you have declared before **as variables of your object**. Instead it `echo`s the variables you have just defined **within** your function `sam()`, which are - of course - undefined.

This should work:

```
class Roxy {
   public $name;
   public $xclass;
   public $age;

   public function sam() {
        echo $this -> name;
        echo $this -> xclass;
        echo $this -> age;
   }

}

$kush= new Roxy();

$kush->name="sachin";
$kush->xclass=12;
$kush->age=21;

$kush->sam(); // > sachin > 12 > 21
```

+ `class` is a reserved keyword in php. You shouldn't use it. Instead use xclass for example.

Comment: `class` isn't a reserved namespace, it's a reserved keyword. Using it as a property is not the best of ideas, fair enough, but it won't cause problems if you do

Comment: Thanks for the hint about `class` being a reserved keyword instead of a reserved namespace. Still I think it's not a good idea to use.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Although "class" is a reserved keyword, it can still be used. This I tested with PHP 5.4. Yet as you say, it's not the best of ideas, I agree.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: That's exactly what I said: _"it WON'T cause problems if you do"_. But that's irrelevant, since we all agree that doing so is a bad idea

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Indeed. I shy away from using any type of reserved word, be it using classes, SQL, PHP etc. It's always best not to. Cheers

Answer (score 5):

This is not how oop works: Here is a working example of what you are trying to achieve:

```
<?php
class roxy
{
   public $name;
   public $class;
   public $age;

   public function sam()
   {
       echo $this->name;
       echo $this->class;
       echo $this->age;
   }

}

$kush= new roxy();
$kush->name="sachin";
$kush->class=12;
$kush->age=21;
$kush->sam();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$this` to refer to a class' own attributes. To get the behaviour you want change your class to look like this:

```
class roxy
{
    public $name;
    public $class;
    public $age;
    public function sam()
    {
        echo $this->name;
        echo $this->class;
        echo $this->age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- your variables are defined inside the function and not the class!

2- they should be declared as public (as well as the function)

3- you should use $this to call them inside the function